# At the Center for Neuroscience of the University of Heidelberg?

Tags: prepositions

In the sentence

> At the Center for Neuroscience at the University of Heidelberg

which I am pretty sure is correct, can I replace the second at by an "of" for aesthetic reasons? I am asking because the quote above is part of a sentence listing internships I did, currently containing 6 "at"s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't do that, personally.  You could, but it sounds a bit contrived.  I would just say simply *at the University of Heidelberg Center for Neuroscience*.  This usage is quite common when you are speaking of an entity that is contained within another entity.

Comment: +1 or ... At the University of Heidelberg's Center for ...

Comment: @TRomano I thought of including that possibility as well, which is similar to the OP's use of the word *of*.  In the end, my feeling is that one is more likely to use that in an informal mention of the center, and would omit the possessive in a formal listing of internships.

Answer (score 0):

'University of Heidelberg' is the proper name of the university and should not be changed. 'Of' in this context means belonging to Heidelberg while 'at' means being situated in Heidelberg. It is in the former context the names of universities are used. For example: University of Singapore. However, where there are more than one place where the university is  represented, the 'at' can be used next to the relevant place, for example, University of California at Los Angeles.

Comment: The actual name for UCLA is *University of California, Los Angeles*.  That suggests *University of Heidelberg, Center for Neuroscience* as well.